# Is it possible create new account in MySQL from Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I need use SQL without working with MySQL. Just from Java create account, databases, export and import databases. Its possible? Or I should prefer XML for it?

Comment: *"Or I should prefer XML for it?"* - You can't create MySQL accounts using XML ... AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

you can of course do it via a Statement that executes the MySQL commands for creating users:

```
Connection con = ...; //initialize your mysql connection
Statement s = con.createStatement();
s.execute( "CREATE USER ... " );
```

See the mysql page [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) for the syntax of `create user` statement.